# Django one-to-many-to-many relationships admin

Tags: django, model, many-to-many

I want to build a small learning management system where you have modules and module tests. Of course module tests have questions and questions have many answers. So in the end you will up with the module-questions-answers paradigm (one-many-many). For that I build the following model (simplified)

*models.py*

```
class Module(models.Model):
 title = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class ModuleTest(models.Model):
 module = models.ForeignKey(Module)

class ModuleTestQuestion(models.Model)
 module_test = models.ForeignKey(ModuleTest)
 title = models.CharField(max_length=200) #question text

class ModuleTestQuestionOption(models.Model)
 module_test_question = models.ForeignKey(ModuleTestQuestion)
 title = models.CharField(max_length=100) #answer text
 correct = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

So far so good. This kind of approach works perfectly. The downside is that since django can't give you inlines within inlines the administration of such a structure is painful. Instead of having creating a module test, then create the questions and then create the answers within the admin, I would really like to create them in one swoop on one admin page.

Does anyone have an idea how i would change my model, so this can be realized?